# basic shortcode - Why 1st paragraph not wrapped in p tag, but 2nd is

Tags: shortcode, wp-autop

I'm working on a basic plugin that adds shortcodes for columns, buttons, panels, ect. Nothing new here. I haven't altered wpautop in anyway; I've tried removing it and delaying it - no change. What happens with all shortcodes used is, the first paragraph isn't wrapped within a p tag (the p tags are actually appearing directly after the first paragraph and empty), but all paragraphs after the first within the same shortcode ARE wrapped in p tags. I need to figure out WHY the first paragraph isn't being wrapped.

Function:

```
function vc_shortcode_panel($atts, $content = null) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'type' => ''
  ), $atts) );
 return '<div class="panel ' . $type . '">' . do_shortcode( trim($content) ) . '</div>';
 }
add_shortcode('panel', 'vc_shortcode_panel');
```

Shortcode:

```
[panel type=""]paragraph 1

paragraph 2[/panel]
```

Output looks like this:

```
<div class="panel">
  paragraph 1
  <p></p>
  <p>paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

I know if I add a line break between the [panel] and the first paragraph, it will then wrap that first paragraph in a p tag. But shouldn't shortcodes be able to be formatted correctly without requiring that line break? What am I doing wrong and can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an example of [the `wpautop()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)'s intended purpose. From the Codex:

> Changes double line-breaks in the text into HTML paragraphs (`<p>`...`</p>`).

Note that [the example provided in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop#Basic_usage) explicitly uses a string that begins with a line-break for this very purpose:

```
<?php
$some_long_text = // Start Text
Some long text
that has many lines

and paragraphs in it.
// end text

echo wpautop($some_long_text);
?>
```

The above results in following markup:

```
<p>Some long text<br/>
that has many lines</p>
<p>and paragraphs in it.</p>
```

The reasoning behind this functionality is that double line-breaks in HTML markup are interpreted as generic whitespace and render as a single line-break in the DOM. In order to properly display a double line-break, you either have to insert `<br />` elements or make use of default paragraph-element styling, which is what WordPress does.

As the first line of your example contains no line-breaks, no paragraph or `<br />` elements are added, as no line-break formatting needs to be preserved.

See the [`wpautop()` function's source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L189) for the exact implementation.

Comment: On a side note, I copied and pasted that example verbatim, but it really _should_ have quotation marks around the `$some_long_text` string; in it's present form it __is not__ valid PHP.

Comment: But why would the first `<p></p>` be empty? Should it not be there then?

Comment: Huh. You're right - that is something funky! I can't honestly account for that... I don't believe that that this is an intended product of the `wpautop()` function... you may have stumbled across a bug, unless this is how the core devs have chosen to maintain that whitespace - I'll have to look into this all further...